# Monto para asiento contable

Tags: sql

Adelante explico los detalles

Necesito que basado en la bodega Destino sume los montos de cada linea de la tabla DeTraslado para asignarlo como el monto del debe o haber en un asiento contable.

Información: Dos Tablas

T1 : DeTraslados: Guarda cada una de las lineas del traslado (de inventarios) con numero de traslado, el costo del articulo y la cantidad traslada hacia la bodega de destino (esas 4 columnas son las que afectan mi consulta)

T2 : MaTraslados: Es el maestro de Traslados,  guarda el numero de traslado (llave) y el total correspondiente a DeTraslados

Al hacer el traslado se me despliega una ventana (con formato de asiento) que posteriormente guardara los datos como el asiento contable, y me pide los valores Suma(este valor lo toma tanto para debe como para haber según la predefinicion del lugar de la cuenta contable (debe o haber)), NOTA, TITULAR Y CCOSTO

Estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(Cantidad*Costo) AS Suma, \[Numero\] AS NOTA, 0 AS TITULAR, 0 AS CCOSTO 
FROM DeTraslados 
INNER JOIN MaTraslados ON DeTraslados.NumTraslado = MaTraslados.NumTraslado 
WHERE DeTraslados.Destino IN (01, 02, 04)
```

No me da error al momento de intentar mostrar los datos en la ventana pero solo me asigna: Numero en NOTA, 0 en TITULAR y 0 en CCOSTO, pero lo mas importante que es el monto no lo pone en la posición que se le indicó

**Adjunto imágenes de respaldo

[image: Predeficion de las cuentas en asientos]

[image: Resultado]